# Filter a mysql query using php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to retrieve multiple results from MySQL and have to use the same query multiple times with the addition of  `"and"`  to the `"where"` clause.
For Example:

my first query:

```
$class = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '8'";
```

My other queries:

```
$class8a ="SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '8' AND SECTION= 'A'";
$class8b ="SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '8' AND SECTION= 'B'";
```

...etc.
Similarly for all other classes in the school. 
I am currently writing the queries again and again but I was wondering if there is any simpler way of doing this by retrieving the result from the database in an array and then filtering it for subsequent queries.

Comment: Essentially Yes, fetch all results using `SELECT * FROM schools` and then filter in php?

Comment: yes. so that i do not have to write half the query again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$class8a ="SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '8' AND SECTION= 'A'";
```

You're storing a query into a text variable, which means that you intend to use it later on, and there you will write `$class8a`:

```
$db->query($class8a);
```

This probably leaves you with another problem: you have to *know* that class 8, section A *exists*. If a class is added or removed you need to rewrite your code, which is not efficient as well as being frightfully error prone.

So **one way** of doing this could be to fetch all classes and all sections in your schools and populate an **array**:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT class, section FROM schools";
$stmt  = $db->query($query);
$pairs = [ ]; // or $pairs = array(); in older PHPs
while ($pair = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!array_key_exists($pair['class'], $pairs) {
        $pairs[$pair['class']] = [];
    }
    $pairs[$pair['class']][$pair['section']] = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '{$pair['class']}' AND section = '{$pair['section']}'";
}
```

Now you can use `$pairs['8']['A']` instead of `$class8a`. Or you can *define* the variable using variable variables:

```
while ($pair = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $nameOfVar = $pair['class'] . strtolower($pair['section']);
    $$nameOfVar = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '{$pair['class']}' AND section = '{$pair['section']}'";
}
```

But with named variables you still don't have an easy way of *knowing* whether `$class7f` exists or not (you *can* use `isset` but I feel it's awkward), much less to *enumerate* them or know which classes *might* exist, while with an array, you can (using `foreach`).

You also have a subtler problem if someone ever creates an ancillary section (do you have those?) and calls it, say, `A'` instead of `A*` or `A+` or `A1/2` "because a star, a plus or an additional half could be perceived as judgmental by parents or pupils". While `A'` is perceived as a SQL injection attack by the code: `WHERE section='A'';` is a syntax error.

And you now have to keep in memory lots of similar queries.

## Recommended solution

Even better would be, once you have classes and sections, simply building the queries on the fly:

```
$classQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class=? AND section=?');
```

Then to execute, with PDO this simply *works*:

```
$classQuery->execute([ '8', "A'" ]);
```

You can use an array to keep track of things and know which classes exist:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT class, section FROM schools;";
$stmt  = $db->query($query);
$pairs = [ ]; // or $pairs = array(); in older PHPs
while ($pair = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if (!array_key_exists($pair['class'], $pairs) {
        $pairs[$pair['class']] = [];
    }
    $pairs[$pair['class']][] = $pair['section'];
}
```

This allows you to e.g. place a class combo in the HTML:

```
$combo = '<select name="class">';
foreach (array_keys($pairs) as $class) {
     $combo .= "<option value=\"{$class}\">{$class}</option>";
}
$combo .= "</select>";
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where I can read more about this. I am new to mysql and do not know how to retrieve and display the results.

Comment: Uhm. You would need some tutorial on PDO. Despite its bombastic title claim, I find this quite complete and informative (but feel free to google more!): https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 1):

put all classes in one array e.g. `$classArray = ['8','9'];`  and sections in another array e.g. `$sectionArray = ['A','B'];` now you run a query to iterate over `classArray` and then `sectionArray` e.g.

```
foreach($classArray as $className)
{
  foreach($sectionArray as $sectionName)
  {
          $qry = 'SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class="'.$className. '" AND section ="'.$sectionName.'"';
    // Your Code 
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please suggest where I can find out more about this? I mean the exact method of doing this?  This I am asking because I don't know how I shall retrieve my results and put them in separate columns of the php table.

Comment: look into php docs @ php,net , you will learn about loops and Arrays and iterators

Answer (score 1):

You can use variable to store your similar queries for example

`$and ="AND SECTION= 'A'";`

and use the variable within your main query for your specific requirements.

like 
`$class = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '8'";`

and

`$class = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE class= '8' $and";`

You can set the query into any variable using your conditions.
I think this make sense.